# How to define a distribution that 90% of the time gives me 0?

Tags: simulation

This maybe a simple question, but I am just stuck with it.
I want to do some simulation, say with 0.9 probability, I get a 1, and 0.1 probability get a 0.

How would I do that? Where should I start?

Thanks!

Comment: `RandomChoise[{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0}]` assuming that `RandomChoise` has a constant probabality of choosing every element

Comment: There is an incongruence between title and content of the question?

Comment: @k_v Try `RandomChoice[{0.1, 0.9} -> {0, 1}, n]` to do the weighting instead, it's much more flexible this way.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry that I forgot to accept it after a long time! I used to accept answers pretty quickly, but I was suggested that perhaps I should have waited for more people to have a go with it. This is case, I simply forgot to come back and accept it!

Comment: No problem.  I happened to come across it.  Sometimes I forget for a while, too. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`BernoulliDistribution` is a perfect fit for this.

```
RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1 - 0.1], {50}]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Also, as kguler states, you can use `RandomChoice`, but the benefit of `BernoulliDistribution` is that you can operate it also as an abstract distribution, not only a source of randomness. For instance, you can compute its symbolic variance:

```
Variance[BernoulliDistribution[1 - 1/n]]
```

> (1 - 1/n)/n

Comment: `RandomChoice` does have the benefit of [being compilable](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions), unlike `BernoulliDistribution[]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Are you sure? `f = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, RandomChoice[{.9, .1} -> {1, 0}, n]]` seems to compile for me, with the function `RandomChoiceWeights` in the result of `CompilePrint`

Comment: @blochwave, Oops, my bad.  I forgot the `_Integer` on that one but not the others. :/  Now the compiled version is faster until about 10^4 or 10^5.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: No problem! Admittedly performance tails off for large samples...

Answer (score 6):

```
RandomChoice[{.9, .1} -> {1, 0}, 10]
```

(*
{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}
*)

**Timing results**

- `Timing[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[.9], {10^8}];]` (* {3.38014, Null} *)
- `Timing[RandomChoice[{.9, .1} -> {1, 0}, 10^8];]`(* {5.64937, Null} *)
- `dist[] := If[RandomReal[] > 0.9, 0, 1]; Timing[Table[dist[], {i, 10^8}];]` (* {13.9842, Null} *)

One nice property of `RandomChoice` is that it can be generalized, for instance:

```
RandomChoice[{.7, .2, .1}-> {0, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: "One nice property of RandomChoice is that it can be generalized..." - so too can BernoulliDistribution...

Comment: @rasher How can the `BernoulliDistribution` be generalized to give the same as `RandomChoice[{.3, .2, .4, .05, .05}-> {-2, 5, 3, 2, "A"}]` naturally, i.e., without multiple calls?

Comment: Multiple Bernoulli is just Multinomial, hence, with one call to multinomial, this gives same kind of results as RandomChoice: `RandomSample@
  Flatten@MapThread[
    ConstantArray[#1, #2] &, {#3, 
     RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[#1, #2]]}] &` given count, probs. and returned values... no real reason to do so, but it *is* one call to a distribution ;=)

Comment: @rasher Could you give a working example, with actual values (as I did)?  For instance, I couldn't see how to get your example to work with five probabilities and five variables.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure, e.g. `RandomSample@
   Flatten@MapThread[
     ConstantArray[#1, #2] &, {#3, 
      RandomVariate[
       MultinomialDistribution[#1, #2]]}] &[20, {.3, .2, .4, .05, \
.05}, {-2, 5, 3, 2, "A"}]` gives same kind of result as `RandomChoice[{.3, .2, .4, .05, .05}-> {-2, 5, 3, 2, "A"},20]`. But again, no real reason to do this (I suppose if one were generating the dist. probs. programmatically *and* wanted to use probabilistic functions against them also this has a place) - just some gentle leg-pulling...

Comment: @rasher  Thanks... but wow.... so much more complicated!

Answer (score 5):

Take a uniform random distribution and check if it is above some threshold (0.9 in your case).

For example:

```
dist[] := If[RandomReal[] > 0.9, 0, 1];
Table[dist[], {i, 100}]
```

Comment: No need for the `i` in the iterator.